# Make a CMD effect on docker run but not in docker start

Tags: python, django, docker, requirements.txt, docker-image

#### Background:

I'm deploying a python-web(django) environment using docker.

And I want to make a clean docker image, containing only the run-time environment, but not the source code, then volume the code in.

My docker image repository: https://github.com/EaseCloud/docker-django

```
FROM python:latest
MAINTAINER huangwc@easecloud.cn

WORKDIR /var/app

ENV PROJECT=app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove -y

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install gunicorn django greenlet eventlet

COPY ./startup.sh /var
RUN chmod +x /var/startup.sh

VOLUME ["/var/app", "/var/app/media"]

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/var/startup.sh"]
```

So, I'm now running a script `startup.sh` using the `CMD` command.

The script content is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
if [ ! -e ./manage.py ]; then
    django-admin startproject $PROJECT .
fi
if [ -f ./requirements.txt ]; then
    pip install -r requirements.txt
fi
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 4 -k eventlet $PROJECT.wsgi
```

In the script, I will do the below:

1. try to start a django project if no source volume in;
2. install the PyPI requirements in `requirements.txt`;
3. start the gunicorn service;

---

#### Question:

Now, because ordinary I will volume the source code in, including the `requirements.txt`, so I possibly have different PyPI requirements on different docker container instance.

I want to make the line:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

only executing when I call `docker run`:

```
docker run --name myproject \
    -v /var/django/myproject:/var/app \
    -e PROJECT=myproject \
    huangwc/django
```

But I don't want the command run when I call:

```
docker start myproject
```

Is there a good solution to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't run a separate script when you use `docker run` rather than relying on the images `CMD`? e.g. `docker run huangwc/django /prep_script.sh`

Comment: @Matt, That sounds a considerable solution, so can you make a detailed answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on Matt's comment a little bit and add another idea to accomplish the ultimate goal as I understand it based on your script.

## Idea #1: Set Development Environment Variable

You can control whether certain components run if you modified the startup script to be something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
if [ $DEVELOPMENT ]; then
  if [ -f ./requirements.txt ]; then
      pip install -r requirements.txt
  fi
  if [ ! -e ./manage.py ]; then
      exec django-admin startproject $PROJECT .
  fi
else
  exec gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 4 -k eventlet $PROJECT.wsgi
fi
```

Then set the `DEVELOPMENT` environment variable to `true` or some other text when running your container in the development environment. Without it (by default) the container starts gunicorn and assumes all dependencies are there and no code is mounted over what was built in the image.

## Idea #2: Separate Out Actions

I'm a big fan of images "that just work" when run by default. So, if you can stipulate that your default is that the image is built with all the code and the dependencies already (from the build process). Then your resulting `CMD` of`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 4 -k eventlet $PROJECT.wsgi` should be sufficient to do this.

Then on the development side just have instructions to manually override the `CMD` at `docker run` with something like `pip install -r requirements.txt && django-admin startproject $PROJECT .`. If helpful, you could just make it a separate script `dev.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
pip install -r requirements.txt
exec django-admin startproject $PROJECT .
```

Comment: But for #2, because I'm new in docker, can I ask: is is possible to call multiple `docker run` on a same container? And how can I keep that instructions in *docker-compose*?

Comment: You can run multiple commands, if you are using `--name myproject` the next `docker run` will pick up where the last `run` left off. You can also use `docker exec` if you want to run something in an already running container. I don't believe you can add this behaviour to your `compose.yml`